# Monitoring storage space on windows mobile

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, storage

In a native(c++) windows mobile app.  There are ways to be notified of low memory, `WM_HIBERNATE`, and low power, `RequestPowerNotifications()`.

Is there any way to be notified when storage space is running low?  Or must an app just poll regularly with `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no system notifications for storage space.